# Weird looking "json" code - how can I convert it to php/array/json?

Tags: mysql, json, database, wordpress

I have this data code and I need the data in PHP array/object format, anyone recognizes this?

It looks like json but its not. I have pulled it from a WordPress database

```
a:3:{i:0;a:10:{s:17:"availability_type";s:6:"custom";s:9:"from_date";s:16:"2020-05-14 18:00";s:13:"from_week_day";s:1:"1";s:10:"from_month";s:1:"1";s:9:"from_time";s:0:"";s:11:"to_week_day";s:1:"1";s:8:"to_month";s:1:"1";s:7:"to_date";s:16:"2020-05-14 18:00";s:7:"to_time";s:0:"";s:10:"is_bokable";s:3:"yes";}i:1;a:10:{s:17:"availability_type";s:6:"custom";s:9:"from_date";s:11:"2020-05-15 ";s:13:"from_week_day";s:1:"1";s:10:"from_month";s:1:"1";s:9:"from_time";s:0:"";s:11:"to_week_day";s:1:"1";s:8:"to_month";s:1:"1";s:7:"to_date";s:11:"2020-05-15 ";s:7:"to_time";s:0:"";s:10:"is_bokable";s:3:"yes";}i:2;a:10:{s:17:"availability_type";s:6:"custom";s:9:"from_date";s:11:"2020-05-27 ";s:13:"from_week_day";s:1:"1";s:10:"from_month";s:1:"1";s:9:"from_time";s:0:"";s:11:"to_week_day";s:1:"1";s:8:"to_month";s:1:"1";s:7:"to_date";s:11:"2020-05-27 ";s:7:"to_time";s:0:"";s:10:"is_bokable";s:3:"yes";}}
```

Comment: It's not JSON. https://www.php.net/unserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my bad english.
This is a serialized string, you can use `unserialize()` to convert to an array.

https://www.php.net/unserialize